# using turtlebot tf's for another robot

Tags: turtlebot, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I have an eddie robot running the package "eddiebot" for it's integration with ros.
the eddiebot package uses the turtlebot APIs.
so I was wondering if I can use the Turtlebot code regarding the tf configurations for the eddie, and if so were I can find that code to port it to the eddie.
the only difference between the eddie and the turtlebot it's that it doesn't have an IMU.
so I'll need to disable that part of the code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61291/using-turtlebot-tf%27s-for-another-robot/) by [konet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4438/konet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tf frames for the robot are published by robot_state_publisher which parses the URDF of the robot. Eddie should have a URDF that is loaded. If you launch minimal.launch in edditbot_bringup you should get the tf frame automatically.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0